# Let $z$ be a complex number. Find $\text{lim}_{n\rightarrow \infty}\ z^n$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Question: Let $z$ be a complex number. Find $\text{lim}_{n\rightarrow \infty}\ z^n$.

My Attempt:

1. Let $|z|<1$. Then $\text{lim}_{n\rightarrow \infty}\ z^n=0$: Choose $\epsilon>0$. $$|z ^n-0|=|z^n|=|z|^n <\epsilon\implies n\ \text{ln}\ |z|<\ \text{ln}\ \epsilon.$$ For $|z|<1$, $\ \text{ln}\ |z|<0$. Hence, $n>\frac{\text{ln}\ \epsilon}{ \text{ln}\ |z|}$. So, choose $N= \Big\lfloor\frac{\text{ln}\ \epsilon}{ \text{ln}\ |z|}\Big\rfloor+1$.
2. Let $|z|>1$ then $|\frac{1}{z}|<1$. Hence  $\text{lim}_{n\rightarrow \infty}\ \frac{1}{z^n}=0$, which implies that $\text{lim}_{n\rightarrow \infty}\ z^n= \infty$.
3. Let $|z|=1$. I want to find $\text{lim}_{n\rightarrow \infty}\ z^n$.

I have no idea about case 3. But I know that for case 3 $z^n \not\rightarrow 0$, because $$|z|=1 \implies |z^n|=|z|^n =1 \implies |z^n-0| = 1.$$ So choose $\epsilon =\frac{1}{2}$. Hence $z^n \not\rightarrow 0$.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Write in polar form then it will be obvious

Comment: For $3)$, just because $z^n\not\to 0,$ doesn't mean $z^n$ doesn't converge. There is at least one case where $z^n$ does converge: namely $z=1,$ because $1^n\to 1.$

Comment: All that's left is to prove that $z=1$ is the *only* case where it converges. (Hint: Use Cauchy's criterion - show that it fails for $z^n$ unless $z=1$.)

Comment: If you set $z=-1$ you can easily see that there is no limit in general case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\vert z \vert = 1$ and $z^n$ converges to $a$, then given $\frac{\varepsilon}{2}>0,\ \exists\ N$ such that $\ \vert z^n - a \vert < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}\quad \forall\ n\geq N.\ $ Therefore,

$\vert a - z^N \vert = \vert z^N-a \vert < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}\quad $ and $\quad \vert z^{N+1}-a \vert < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}.\ $ Therefore,

$\vert z^{N+1} - z^N \vert = \vert a - z^N + z^{N+1}-a \vert \leq \vert z^N-a \vert + \vert a-z^{N+1} \vert < \varepsilon, \implies \underbrace{\vert z^{N} \vert}_{=1} \vert z - 1 \vert < \varepsilon. $

Since $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary, this means that $\vert z - 1 \vert < \varepsilon$ for *all* $\frac{\varepsilon}{2}>0,$ which can only happen if $z=1.$

To summarise, if $\vert z \vert = 1$ and $z^n$ converges, then $z=1.$